# how to provide C algo lib to both iOS and Android platform

Tags: android, ios, c, algorithm

we are developing some signal process algorithm on mobile platform, using C language, but we want to keep the algo a secret to lower the source code leakage risk.

how can i provide the algo to iOS and Android to meet this requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obfuscating C-based binaries to avoid decompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273610/obfuscating-c-based-binaries-to-avoid-decompilation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a obfuscator to make it harder to decompile your code, but this only makes it harder to reverse re-engeneer the algorithm.

Depending on the setting you can also move the code from the app/iOS program into a web-service. This way the code would only be present on the host that runs the service which is 100% under you control. Disadvantages are:

- maintaining a server (costs ...)
- time delay to send and reseive data to/ from the service
- the computational load of all users is on your server
- ...